# VBA find Value in Active Column

Tags: vba, excel

In the picture you can see my excel worksheet:

[image]

With the CommandButton (red circle) i can add new rows (blue circle) to the table. Range of the table is N to BI.

After i added the new rows i want my code that he jumps one cell to the left and find in this column the first Value "MFG" (green lines and circles). After that i want that he copies the color of "MFG1", which stand left from "MFG" and add it to the new Row.

I am not sure how to do that. Hope someone can help me.

This i my Code so far:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    Dim lastrow As Long

    Dim year As String
    Dim month As String

    Dim faa As Integer
    Dim faa1 As Integer
    Dim faa2 As Integer
    Dim faa3 As Integer
    Dim AGA As Integer
    Dim AGA1 As Integer

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("N1:BI1").Find(What:=year, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lastrow, rng.Column), Cells(2, rng.Column + 11)).Find(What:=month, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            ' Add the new rows to the table
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Value = "DEL"
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                faa = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, faa).Value = "FAA"
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                faa3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 2
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, faa3).Value = "FAA3"
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                faa2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 3
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, faa2).Value = "FAA2"
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                faa1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 4
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, faa1).Value = "FAA1"
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                AGA = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 5
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, AGA).Value = "AGA"
            End If
            If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("N" & lastrow)) Then
                AGA1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 6
                ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, AGA1).Value = "AGA1"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    ' Jumps to the left and select cell
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, AGA1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select 

    ' Here i need to find the Value "MFG" in the column and copy the color.
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA so my Code maybe looks not really good.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the rows, store the last inserted row in a variable

```
lastInsertedRow
```

Then search for the row with the first MFG

```
rowIdx = Columns(19).Find(What:="MFG", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

Copy color from the left one

```
colorToCopy = Range("R" & rowIdx).Interior.Color
```

Set color for the inserted rows:

```
 Range("T" & lastInsertedRow & ":" & "Z" & lastInsertedRow).Interior.Color = colorToCopy
```

To keep it simple I used the absolute references.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. in fact it works fine. I changed the picture, to show that the new rows can end in a different colomn. So how do i have to change the part `rowIdx = Columns(19).Find(What:="MFG" ... ))` that it will find the Value in the active column?

Comment: You need to find the column number of the first non-empty value in added row (for example using a loop or one of the Excel built-in functions), then set it instead of "19" and repeat for all rows